# Struggling to validate the email when toggling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-container">

      <form method="post" id="email">
          
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="typingA spacing"><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>  Email Address:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="typingEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                  
                  
            </div>
          
      </form>

    <form method="post" id="subject">

        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="subject" class="typingA spacing">Subject:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"name="subject"placeholder="Subject" >
        </fieldset>
    </form>

     <form method="post" id="content">

        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="content" class="typingA spacing">What would you like me to ask?</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="3" placeholder="What would you like me to ask, Sir/Madam?"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
      </form>

      <div id="buttons">

          <button type="submit" id="next" class="btn btn-primary" enabled='enabled'>Next</button>
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </div>
```

The JQuery part:

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

$("#buttons").click(function() {     

        $("#next").click(function() {

            if(isEmail($('#typingEmail').val()) == false)
            {
              $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false); 
            } 

            $("#subject").toggle();
            $("#email").toggle(); 
            

        $("#next").click(function() {

            $("#content").toggle(); 
            $("#email").toggle(); 
            $('#next').attr('disabled', true);  
        });
        });

    });
```

What I am trying to do is validate the email. if it is valid, the "next button" should enable, else it should not enable. I tried but didn't succeed. I appreciate your time and help. Ta!

> Note I tried to find similar topic on StackOverflow but didn't find it. So, just a humble
> request, dont report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to disable and enable the next button when the email is valid or not valid, here is a workaround, i don't know whether it cover your requirement or not.

```js
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

$(function(){
  var $emailInput = $('#typingEmail');
  var $nextBtn = $('#next');
  function checkIfEmailOk(){
    return isEmail($emailInput.val());
  }
  function toggleNextByEmail(){
     $nextBtn.prop('disabled', !checkIfEmailOk());
  }
  // or you can listen the 'blur' event
  // but the validation will only triggered after your cursor moved out from the input area 
  // and the 'input' event may need some polyfill in lower versions of IE 
  $emailInput.on('input', function(){
    toggleNextByEmail();
  });
  // disable the next button's onclick event when the email is not valid
  $nextBtn.on('click', function(e){
    if(!checkIfEmailOk()){
      // email not ok
      e.preventDefault();
      $emailInput.focus();
    }
  });
  // if you want to check the email input and toggle the next button when domready
  toggleNextByEmail();
});
```

You can try it in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/minganzi/pen/gOWgqym).